# PingOptions.TTL in vb.net always shows 128 as the result

Tags: vb.net, ping

I'm coding a simple ping command in vb.net using the System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingReply and System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingOptions. But the PingOptions.Ttl always shows 128 as the output. Below is a part of my code:

```
        Dim buffer As Byte() = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data)

        Dim Myreply As System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingReply = MyPing.Send("10.99.162.201", 1000, buffer, options)

        If Myreply.Status = Net.NetworkInformation.IPStatus.Success Then

        PingResult = ("Reply from" & " " & Myreply.Address.ToString & ":" & _
        "bytes=" & Myreply.Buffer.Length.ToString & _
        " " & "time=" & Myreply.RoundtripTime.ToString & "ms" & " " & "TTL=" & options.Ttl)

        ElseIf Myreply.Status = Net.NetworkInformation.IPStatus.TimedOut Then
            PingResult = ("Request timed out.")
        Else
            PingResult = ("Error")
        End If
```

Can somebody help me check what is missing to get the correct result? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Windows OS **TTL is 128**
and Linux's TTL is 64